# Select the first visible cell in every sheet with a loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use the below **VBA** to select the **first visible cell** in a filtered range:

```
Sub Postioning_Option_01()
Sheet1.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Select
End Sub
```

Now, instead of only applying this `VBA` to `Sheet1` I want to **loop through** all sheets. 
Therefore, I tried to go with this `VBA`:

```
Sub Postioning_Option_02()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
b.Select
b.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Select
Next b
End Sub
```

When I run this `VBA` I get error `Object variable or With block variable not set`. 
What do I need to change in the `VBA` to make it work?

Comment: Maybe one of the sheets has no autofilter? If so it will give you an error. It happens to me with your first code, because I have no Autofilter on my sheet. Try `If b.AutofilterMode Then` and your code between the if.

Comment: Is there a way to identify if an autofilter is set in a sheet and ignore this sheet for the loop?

Comment: This error will occur if there are no visible cells. As a matter of principle: Don't set what you want to see on tabs that you aren't looking at. Therefore the trouble you take is quite wasted. The time to set and select is when a tab gets activated. Use the Worksheet_Activate event where you deal with one sheet at a time.

Comment: And for the one upvoting Variatus comment, is as wrong as he is. Try op code in a sheet with no Autofilter, then try the same code in a sheet with all it's rows hidden. You'll be surprised which error are you getting and which one is OP getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will skip sheets with no autofilter:

```
Sub Postioning_Option_02()

    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        If b.AutoFilterMode Then
            b.Select
            b.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Select
        End If
    Next b

End Sub
```

Comment: Why ever would one select all the tabs in a workbook, one after the other, faster than the eye can follow?

Comment: Variatus... This is OP's code just tweaked so he won't get errors when a sheet doesn't have an Autofilter in... why would you even downvote my answer without reading OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

### A Small AutoFilter Study

Nothing special about the first 4 subs, but the last 2 look a little bit deeper, but might be out of context.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Positioning_Option_01()
    If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1) _
          .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Select
    Else
    End If
End Sub

Sub Postioning_Option_02()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        b.Activate
        If b.AutoFilterMode Then
            b.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1) _
              .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Select
        Else
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub Positioning_Option_01_With()
    With Sheet1
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            With .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1) _
              .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2)
                .Select
            End With
        Else
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub Postioning_Option_02_With()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        b.Activate
        With b
            If .AutoFilterMode Then
                With .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1) _
                  .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2)
                    .Select
                End With
            Else
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Sub Pos_Offset()
    With Sheet1
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            ' The following range refers to the range below headers containing
            ' data and one empty row range below data.
            With .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1)
                ' If no match in AutoFilter, after applying "SpecialCells"
                ' the cell in the row below data will be selected. You can't
                ' tell if it is contained in "AutoFilter.Range".
                With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2)
                    .Select
                    Debug.Print .Address, .Value
                End With
            End With
        Else
            ' AutoFilterMode is False
            MsgBox "AutoFilterMode is set to 'False'."
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub Pos_Actual()
    With Sheet1
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            ' The range below headers containing data.
            With .AutoFilter.Range
                With .Rows(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
                    ' If no match in AutoFilter, after applying SpecialCells
                    ' in the following line, the following error occurs:
                    ' "Run-time error '1004': No cells were found."
                    ' Therefore:
                    On Error Resume Next
                    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2)
                        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                            ' The are no visible cells.
                            MsgBox "No visible cells."
                        Else
                            .Select
                            Debug.Print .Address, .Value
                        End If
                        On Error GoTo 0
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        Else
            ' AutoFilterMode is False
            MsgBox "AutoFilterMode is set to 'False'."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```