# Loop and select ranges if some sheets contain an AutoFilter and others not

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets. Some of them contain an `AutoFilter`. Some others not. 
Now, I want to loop through all of them and

a) if they have an `Autofilter` the **first non-hidden cell** below the `AutoFilter` should be selected. 
b) if **all rows are hidden** below the `AutoFilter` the `Cell B29` should be selected. 
c) if **there is no** `AutoFilter` in the sheet the `Cell CB29` should be selected.

---

I tried to combine the solutions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080648/select-the-first-visible-cell-in-every-sheet-with-a-loop-in-vba) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081338/check-if-autofilter-range-is-completely-hidden?noredirect=1#comment109800544_62081338) but could not make it work so far:

```
Sub Select_Range ()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
    If b.AutoFilterMode _
    Or b.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 _
    Then
    b.Select
    b.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Select
    Else
    b.Select
    b.Range("B29").Select
    End If
Next b
End Sub
```

I get `runtime error 91`.

What do I need to change in my loop to make it work?

Comment: Your second condition, `b.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1` will always be true, because your filter is in row 29, so there at least row 29 is. In the case that there is no autofilter, then it will most certainly be true. You need to rework that condition inside the `b.AutofilterMode` and counting from row 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AutoFilterMode` is false, no auto filter is active - and in that case `AutoFilter` is not set. This causes the runtime error 91.

You have to check `AutoFilterMode` and `AutoFilter` in two separate `If`-statements because you need to ensure that AutoFilter is set before checking it. VBA will always evaluate all parts of an IF-statement.

Try something like

```
For Each b In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    b.Select
    b.Range("B29").Select
    If b.AutoFilterMode Then
        If b.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            b.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Select
        End If
    End If
Next b
```

(you should think about better variable names, `b` is really not a good name for a worksheet.)

Comment: What you said is all true, but wouldn't also he need to check from row 30? because if he checks the whole column for visible cells, there will always be, at least, the one with the autofilter. Right?

Comment: @Damian: If all rows are filtered, `b.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count` = 1 and therefore the 2nd `If`-condition would be false.

Comment: Didn't think it that way, but still we are assuming that rows 1 to 28 must be hidden, right?

Comment: No because it is just checking the `b.AutoFilter.Range`-cells (which start at row 29)